# How to write multiple function calls in multiple lines in PowerShell?

Tags: function, powershell, multiline

I'm currently playing around on PowerShell, and I'm wondering how I can call multiple functions after eachother, but giving them each their own line.

I currently have this:

```
$leet= $text.replace("a", "4").replace("e", "1").replace("e", "3");
```

But I want it more like this:

```
$leet= $text
    .replace("a", "4")
    .replace("e", "1")
    .replace("e", "3");
```

But PowerShell doesn't really like the newlines, and it doesn't work either when I add the ` to the end of each line followed by another one.

So, am I missing something, or is this not possible in PowerShell?

Comment: You can rearrange periods: `$text.` `replace("a", "4").` etcetera. PowerShell knows more stuff is supposed to follow.

Comment: Further reading: [Natural Line Continuations in PowerShell](https://get-powershellblog.blogspot.com/2017/07/bye-bye-backtick-natural-line.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [Jeroen Mostert notes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69808703/how-to-write-multiple-function-calls-in-multiple-lines-in-powershell#comment123396295_69808703) you can get line continuation for free by specifying the operator (`.`) and then placing the whitespace between it and the right-hand operand:

```
$leet = $text.
    Replace("a", "4").
    Replace("e", "1").
    Replace("e", "3")
```

(note that the last call, `Replace("e", "3")`, does nothing - all the `e`'s have already been replaced by the preceding call)

Comment: That's an answer to my question, thank you!
Regarding your note, it was but a typo but thanks for the reminder. :)